# Handle locale in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, localization, locale

I'm looking to handle locale (localization) data in MongoDB
what would be the best practice to handle locale.

For more clarity consider a document:

```
`{
    "_id" : ObjectId("595a05f2a5ace827b4434d94"),
    "name" : "Broadway Center",
    "url" : "bc.example.net"
}`
```

If I want to have locale value for name & URL (jp_JP, en_US)
assumed document will be

```
`{
    "_id" : ObjectId("595a05f2a5ace827b4434d94"),
   "locale" [{ "name" : "Broadway Center",
    "url" : "bc.example.net"},
    {name" : "ブロードウェイセンター",
    "url" : "bc.example.net/jp"}]
}`
```

Here I want to know what is the right way accomplishment this.

Comment: Read [ask], define "handle locale".

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion. I am not aware of complete use case but I think this way you could reduce overhead to minimum.
See how in your suggestion you have "bc.example.net" already twice in db. I think that is not necessary.

From info I have i suggest this approach:

```
public enum LocaleEnum
{
    En = 1,
    Jp = 2
}

public class LocalDoc
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId mongoId { get; set; }
    public string host { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<LocaleEnum, string> locale { get; set; }

}
```

You can store "bc.example.com" to host variable and have method that constructs full Url from enum and host (string concat). On other hand you can easily query all Jp locale names. Furthermore you are type safe because you use enums as keys.

If you think this solution is not good for your situation please provide more info and restrictions you have and we can find a better solution.

Cheers!